# remove white space before delimiter with sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have data of the following format that I want to input into LibreOffice calc

```
data | num   | num | num     | num
```

For some reason Libreoffice does not think the string "3214 " is a number by default (trailing white space).

I want to replace `(\s)*|` with `|` where `\s` stands for space and `*` for the Kleene star operation. And do this at multiple places in each line (all matches).

I tried:

```
sed  -i 's/(\s)*|/|/' DataStats0914.txt
```

But it has no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you quote it? If you want references, use `\(` and `\)` instead,

Also, note the `g` option, since that pattern apperas multiple times

`sed  -i 's/\s*|/|/g' DataStats0914.txt`

Test case:

`echo 'data | num   | num | num     | num' | sed 's/\s*|/|/g'`

Got:

`data| num| num| num| num`

Comment: laziness of manual reading is the reason. But frankly the man pages intimidate me.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) syntaxes. `(\s*)` matches a sequence of whitespace in [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Perl-derived_regular_expressions) and the many other modern programs that imitate its regexes. Sed uses an older variant of [basic regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) in which parentheses stand for themselves and `\(…\)` is used for grouping. GNU sed (the version on Linux) has an option `-r` to use [extended regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions) (which Perl regexes extend further) instead. Also, `|` stands for itself in BRE but must be preceded by a backslash in ERE.

`s/[ \t]\+|/|/` replaces whitespace followed by a `|` with GNU sed. If you want a POSIX-compliant sed command, use `s/[  ][  ]*|/|/` where each pair of brackets contains a space and a tab, as `\t` and `\+` are GNU extensions. Also, the `s` command only replaces one occurrence per line: add the `g` suffix to replace all occurrences.

```
sed  -i 's/[ \t]\+|/|/g' DataStats0914.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

sed removing spaces:

```
sed -i 's/ *|/|/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythonish three liner, untested:

```
python -c 'import sys
for l in sys.readlines():
    print("| ").join([f.strip() for f in l.strip().split("|")])'
```